# TensorRT Engine fail due to UFF parser error

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, tensorrt

I am attempting to convert my Tensorflow frozen model based on the [pix2pix architecture](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow) to an NVIDIA TensorRT engine. I have the TensorRT 3 version. Though my layers are supported by TensorRT 3, some of them are unsupported by the UFF parser. The problem I am facing is due to the line:

`mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(input, axes=[0, 1, 2], keep_dims=False)`

One of the internal operations is the `squared difference` which is not supported by TensorRT, returning the following error upon execution:

> Converting to UFF graph
>   Warning: keep_dims is not supported, ignoring...
>
> Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: SquaredDifference yet.
>
> Converting as custom op SquaredDifference >
>
> generate_output/generator/decoder_2/batchnorm/moments/SquaredDifference
>   name:
>
> "generate_output/generator/decoder_2/batchnorm/moments/SquaredDifference"
>
> op: "SquaredDifference"
>
> input: "generate_output/generator/decoder_2/batchnorm/Identity"
>
> input: "generate_output/generator/decoder_2/batchnorm/moments/StopGradient"
>
> attr {
>
> key: "T"
>
> value {
>
> type: DT_FLOAT
>
> }
>
> }
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "scripts/convert_plan.py", line 71, in 
>   data_type
>
> File "scripts/convert_plan.py", line 22, in frozenToPlan
>   text=False,
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/conversion_helpers.py", line 103, in from_tensorflow_frozen_model
>   return from_tensorflow(graphdef, output_nodes, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/conversion_helpers.py", line 75, in from_tensorflow
>   name="main")
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 64, in convert_tf2uff_graph
>   uff_graph, input_replacements)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 51, in convert_tf2uff_node
>   op, name, tf_node, inputs, uff_graph, tf_nodes=tf_nodes)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 28, in convert_layer
>   fields = cls.parse_tf_attrs(tf_node.attr)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 177, in parse_tf_attrs
>   for key, val in attrs.items()}
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 177, in 
>   for key, val in attrs.items()}
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 172, in parse_tf_attr_value
>   return cls.convert_tf2uff_field(code, val)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 146, in convert_tf2uff_field
>   return TensorFlowToUFFConverter.convert_tf2numpy_dtype(val)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py", line 74, in convert_tf2numpy_dtype
>   return np.dtype(dt[dtype])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not AttrValue

I have tried to replace `tf.nn.moments` with 2 alternate methods:

1. `mean = tf.reduce_mean(input, axis = [0, 1, 2], keep_dims=False)`

   `devs_squared = tf.multiply(input - mean, input - mean)`

   `variance = tf.reduce_mean(devs_squared, axis = [0, 1, 2], keep_dims=False)`

Though the layers are all supported by TensorRT 3, `reduce_mean` is not supported by the UFF parser and it throws the following error:

> UFFParser: Parser error:
>
> generate_output/generator/encoder_2/batchnorm/Mean: Reduce operator not supported

2. Second method:

   `mean = tf.keras.backend.sum(input, axis = [0, 1, 2])`

   `div_factor_1 = input.get_shape().as_list()[0]*input.get_shape().as_list()[1]*input.get_shape().as_list()[2]`

   `mean = mean * (1 / div_factor_1)`

   `devs_squared = tf.multiply(input - mean, input - mean)`

   `variance = tf.keras.backend.sum(devs_squared, axis = [0, 1, 2])`

   `div_factor_2 = devs_squared.get_shape().as_list()[0]*devs_squared.get_shape().as_list()[1]*devs_squared.get_shape().as_list()[2]`

   `variance = variance * (1 / div_factor_2)`

But I am again met with a UFF parser error:

> UFFParser: Parser error: generate_output/generator/encoder_2/batchnorm/Sum: Reduce operator not supported

I also used reduce_sum in alternate 2 instead of keras.backend.sum, to meet the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to do batchnorm with your own code. If there is nothing special about the batchnorm then you should use tensorflow's batchnorm.

I got batchnorm to be converted to tensorrt supported ops by doing this:
1. Specify fused=False in your tensorflow code.
2. Run convert graph with fold_batch_norm option on your frozen graph.
3. Convert the new frozen graph with your conversion script.